# How can I produce an XML document with a DOCTYPE defined using Mule and DataWeave?

Tags: xml, mule, dataweave

I'd like to create a DataWeave transformation that produces an XML document that includes a DOCTYPE like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html 
 PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head><!-- etc. --></head>
  <body><!-- etc. --></body>
</html>
```

I haven't been able to find it in the [DataWeave documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation) so far.  How can I accomplish this in DWL?

I'm using Mule 3.7.2 EE and Anypoint Studio 5.3.0.

Comment: Have you tried putting the doctype declaration in a constant, and output the literal first thing in the body of the transform? (haven't tried myslef)

Answer (score 1):

I've been experimenting some, without any luck. I cant seem to set any custom output that aren't real elements.

When struck with this, I would output a simple placeholder at first (like plc or something, and then use a groovy script after data weave to replace that placeholder with the `<!DOCTYPE` tag.

Hope it helps.